# TowerDefense image import (eclipse,java)

Tags: java, eclipse, image

I've been working on a tower defense game using eclipse and I cannot manage to print out the picture of my tower. Here is some code from the main tower class :

```
public class MainTower {    
    public String TextureFile = ""; 
    public Image texture;
    //tower array that holds up to 150 towers
    public static final MainTower[] towerList = new MainTower[150];          
    //Connecting the Lightning tower to the Main tower class    
    public static final MainTower towerOfLight = new LightningTower(0).getTextureFile("Lightning");

    public MainTower(int id)    {   
        if(towerList[id] != null){      
            System.out.println("[Tower Initialization] Two towers with the same id" + id);
        } else {            
            towerList[id] = this;       
            this.id = id;   
        }       
    }

    public MainTower getTextureFile(String str) {   
        this.TextureFile = str;         
        this.texture = new ImageIcon("/res/tower/" + this.TextureFile + "png").getImage();
        return null;
    } 
}
```

The location is correct the image is a 25x25 png image called Lightning. Here is some code from the layout class :

```
for(int x = 0; x<15; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y<2; y++) {
        if(MainTower.towerList[x *2 +y] != null)
            GUI.drawImage(MainTower.towerList[x * 2 + y].texture, (int) (12 + 12 + 250 + 40 + 12 +(x * towerWidth)), (12*50) + 20 + (y * (int)towerHeight), null);              
    GUI.drawRect((int) (12 + 12 + 250 + 40 + 12 +(x * towerWidth)), (int) ((12*50) + 20  + ((y * towerHeight))), (int)towerWidth,(int)towerHeight);         
        }     
   }
}
```

I've created a grid (boxes) at the bottom of the screen where I wish to place my towers so the player can choose. So I was wondering where am i going wrong so the picture doesn't print out.

Here is the LightningTower class:

```
//Creating a class for Lightning towers
public class LightningTower extends MainTower{

//Setting up Lightning tower id
    public LightningTower(int id){
        super(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't read that code. Please format it correctly.

Comment: why getTextureFile is of type MainTower and why does it return null?

Comment: I reformatted your code the best I could without much java-experience. Maybe you can still improve the formatting yourself to make it more readable?

Comment: Hello, thank you, it is the first time I post here so I have no idea how to get around, I tried fixing it as much as I can.

Comment: It is much better now. If you need more help, then read this help page about formatting: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Because once I change the type to void it gives me an error here : public static final MainTower towerOfLight = new LightningTower(0).getTextureFile("Lightning");

Comment: but then you effectively assign null to the `public static final MainTower towerOfLight ` because you return null! As an option, try `return this`

Comment: and where is `LightningTower` class code?

Comment: I added the LT class code above.

Comment: I changed it to 'return this' but still it doesn't print out the picture

Comment: does `GUI.drawImage(new ImageIcon("/res/tower/Lightning.png").getImage())` draw a texture if you pass it directly?